# Average including blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to average a range but some of the cells are blanks.
The cells should remain blanks, is there a way of including them in an `AVERAGE`?

For example, if I have 2 cells, one is empty and the other is 100, I want the average to be 50

How can I do this?

Comment: What logic determines if a cell should be black? Please edit your post to include what you've already tried

Comment: logic? - some users update it with data, and some did not. the cells of the later will stay empty. I want to calculate the average for all users. so the empty cells should be calculated as zeros

Comment: If I have 2 cells, one is empty and the other is 100, I want the average to be 50

Comment: So when you say black (I.e the colour) you mean *blank*? If so pleas edit your question to clarify

Comment: Thanks for the correction. misspelled.

Answer (score 4):

If your values are in `A1:A2` (for example), try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AVERAGE(0+A1:A2))
```

it forces your blank values to be converted to `0` before taking the average

Comment: This is useful but as an Excel noob it took me a bit to understand you meant the "0+" is the useful bit and not the out of nowhere "SUMPRODUCT()".

Comment: The SUMPRODUCT is also important - it's a nice way to ensure this is treated as an array formula without having to enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (like one of the other answers suggests)

Comment: I don't know what "array formula" means, it seemed to work for me without it 

Comment: If you are using one of the latest versions of Excel (e.g. 365), you'll likely never need to know about array formulas. In 2017, when these answers were written, the SUMPRODUCT (or ctrl+shift+enter) was absolutely necessary to this answer. Google array formulas in Excel if you're more interested. Otherwise, you'll just have to accept it coming from someone who's worked with Excel and array formulae for decades.

Answer (score 2):

You could also Array Formulas
Type

=AVERAGE(0+A1:A2)

and Press Ctrl + Shift and Enter

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column that is never blank (like name of a person) then:

```
=SUM(B1:B100)/COUNT(A1:A100)
```

Where `B` is the column to average and `A` is the name column (never blank). Careful as some people tend to leave `A1` and `B1` as descriptions of the column and if that is the case with you then use `A2:A100` and `B2:B100` otherwise row 1 will be counted to the average.

Comment: The question literally says "average including *blank* cells", so the premise of "If you have a column that is never blank" doesn't hold.

Comment: Agreed, in this case @fireattack you would need to manually write where the end of the list is located. Are there 100 rows? Then sum(b1:b100)/100, 99 rows then sum(b1:b100)/99. When I usually make a list with a column that can be left blank I add a name or a date on the same row in another column...

Comment: Or possibly also ```=SUM(B1:B100)/COUNTA(A1:A100)``` in case your "names" (in `A`) are fewer than 100.

Comment: This is how I do it too - works well with pivot tables